# Generated algebra and measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis

Define $\mathcal F := \{[n, n+1) : n \in \mathbb Z \} \subseteq \mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ and let $\Omega_{\mathcal F}$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathcal F$ on $\mathbb R$.

Can someone first give me a concrete discription, which sets belong to $\Omega_{\mathcal F}$?

Then I need to show that a function $f: (\mathbb R, \Omega_{\mathcal F}) \rightarrow (\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$ is measurable iff for all $n \in \mathbb Z $ the restriction $f|_{[n,n+1)}$ is constant.

I barely have a clue what to do here and what be grateful for advice. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$B\in\Omega_{\mathcal F}$ iff it can be written as a union of sets in $\mathcal F$.

Note that this is necessary for $\Omega_{\mathcal F}$ to be a $\sigma$-algeba that contains $\mathcal F$ and also that it is sufficient.

Equivalently you could say that: $$B\in\Omega_{\mathcal F}\iff  B\cap\left[n,n+1\right)\in\left\{ \left[n,n+1\right),\emptyset\right\}\text{ is true for all } n\in\mathbb Z$$

If the restriction of $f$ is constant on $\left[n,n+1\right)$ for
each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ then indeed we have $f^{-1}\left(A\right)\cap\left[n,n+1\right)\in\left\{ \left[n,n+1\right),\emptyset\right\} $
for each $n\in\mathbb{Z}$, showing that $f$ is measurable.

If conversely
the restriction of $f$ on interval $\left[n,n+1\right)$ is not constant
for some $n\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $x,y\in\left[n,n+1\right)$ with $f\left(x\right)\neq f\left(y\right)$
then let $A$ be a Borel-set with $f(x)\in A$ and $f(y)\notin A$.

Then $f^{-1}\left(A\right)\cap\left[n,n+1\right)\notin\left\{ \left[n,n+1\right),\emptyset\right\} $
showing that $f$ is not measurable.